# PHP Modulus with Overflow Integer

Tags: php, math, modulus

I get integer overflow value `7.233907357909E+16` from multiplication.

Now i need to calculate modulus `7.233907357909E+16 % 15`.

How can i solve it, any idea how to do this?

Comment: How are you getting these values at first place

Comment: You could use the PHP's [fmod()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function

Comment: Take the modulus before multiplying. Once you've left the range where integers are exactly represented, you've lost the information.

Answer (score 1):

[You should look into `bcmul` and `bcmod` for arbitrary precision computations.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

[Example:](http://ideone.com/0CWmJQ)

```
$res = bcmul('134334244395933282', '2834783723423487283');
$modRes = bcmod($res, '15');
echo $modRes;
```